# AsyncStorage complains of array and object incompatibility during mergeItem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to figure out why `AsyncStorage` in a React Native app refuses to do a `mergeItem` with my data. My function looks like this:

```
const arrToObj = (array) =>
  array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[Object.keys(item)[0]] = Object.values(item)[0]
    return obj
  }, {})

export const addThingToThing = async (title, thing) => {
  try {
    let subThings = []
    let things = {}
    await AsyncStorage.getItem(THINGS_STORAGE_KEY)
      .then((things) => {
        let subThings = []
        Object.values(JSON.parse(decks))
          .map((thing) => {
            if (Object.keys(thing)[0] === title) {
              subThings = [...Object.values(thing)[0].subThings, subThing]
            }
          })
        return { decks, subThings }
      })
      .then(({ decks, subThings }) => {
        const obj = {
          ...arrToObj(JSON.parse(things)),
          [title]: {
            subThings
          }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
        AsyncStorage.mergeItem(THINGS_STORAGE_KEY,
          JSON.stringify(obj))
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error adding thing to thing: ${error.message}`)
  }
}
```

When I do the thing that executes this I get:

```
13:35:52: {"test":{"subThings":[{"one":"a","two":"a"}]},"test2":{"title":"test2","questions":[]}}
13:35:55: [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Value [{"test":{"title":"test","subThings":[]}},{"test2":{"title":"test2","subThings":[]}}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject]
```

Which is confusing, because when the data is printed out it's an object with `{...}`, but `AsyncStorage` shows an array with `[...]`. Is there something I'm missing? This seems pretty dumb to me and I can't seem to figure out how to get RN to play nice.

PS. IMO the structure of the data is gross, but it's what I'm working with. I didn't decide on it, and I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall working with `AsyncStorage`, and it is fundamentally different than `localStorage` because it returns Promises.

Your code looks fine which makes this super confusing, but I am suddenly suspecting that the problem may be due to a missing `await` keyword.

try:

```
.then(async ({ decks, subThings }) => {
  const obj = {
    ...arrToObj(JSON.parse(things)),
    [title]: {
      subThings
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
  // We are adding await here
  await AsyncStorage.mergeItem(THINGS_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(obj))
})
```

It may be a classic "not waiting for the Promise to resolve" before moving on, async problem. Don't delete this question if so. It will be helpful for others including probably myself in the future.

Here's what I think is happening:

1. JavaScript throws `AsyncStorage.mergeItem()` into the function queue
2. There is no `await` for this function that returns a Promise
3. The interpreter does not wait for it to resolve and immediately moves to the next line of code
4. There is no next line of code, so it returns from the `then()` block 0.1ms later (keep in mind it is implicitly doing `return undefined` which inside an async function is the same as `resolve(undefined)`, with the point being that it is trying to resolve the entire chain back up to `await AsyncStorage.getItem(THINGS_STORAGE_KEY)`
5. `obj` gets garbage collected 0.1ms after that
6. `AsyncStorage.mergeItem()` observes a falsy value where it was expecting `obj`, but I don't actually know for certain. It may not be doing step 5 or 6 and instead detecting that `mergeItem` is still pending when it tries to resolve the `getItem` chain, either way:
7. AsyncStorage then gives a confusing error message

Comment: I had tried using the `await` for the second promise but was getting an error about it being a reserved keyword. Your answer led me to use a slightly different syntax which I'll post below. Thanks!

Comment: Ah right. I will update my answer with the `async` in it. The `then()` function needs to be async to use await inside it.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up using to handle the promises correctly is:

```
export const addThingToThing = async (title, thing) => {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(THINGS_STORAGE_KEY, (err, things) => {
      let subThings = []
      Object.values(JSON.parse(decks))
        .map((thing) => {
          if (Object.keys(thing)[0] === title) {
            subThings = [...Object.values(thing)[0].subThings, subThing]
          }
        })
      const obj = {
        [title]: {
          title,
          subThings
        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
      AsyncStorage.mergeItem(THINGS_STORAGE_KEY,
        JSON.stringify(obj))
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error adding thing to thing: ${error.message}`)
  }
}
```

I saw some other similar examples online that used `.done()` that looked identical to what I'd done other than that call. That may have been something to try as well, but this worked for me.